# Count bits set upto a given position for a 32 bit type

Tags: c, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I am working with an algorithm that performs many popcount/sideways addition up to a given index for a 32 bit type. I am looking to minimize the operations required to perform what I have currently implemented as this:

```
int popcto_test1(unsigned int bitmap[], int idx){
int i = 0,      // index
    count = 0;  // number of set bits
do {
    // Each node contains 8 bitmaps
    if(bitmap[i/32] & 1 << (i & 31)){
        ++count;
    }
    ++i;
} while (i < idx);

return count;
}
```

I am aware of bit twiddling hacks [for 64 bit types](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsFromMSBToPos) but there doesn't seem to be a fast way to do this for 32 bit types.

Is there a better (fewer operations / minimal branching) - or even just an alternative that I can try, ideally with a source?

I am aware (from reading similar posts) that such optimizations are usually not recommended but my project focuses on comparing performance differences of *'optimizations'* - and whether they improve performance or not.

---

I've since run a bunch of performance benchmarks based on the suggested methods, and what I had above (tested 4,000,000 times) and got the following results:

avg popcto_test1 ns=133
avg popcto_test2 // test failed
avg popcto_test3 ns=28
avg popcto_test4 ns=74

where the test functions were as followed:
**The failed test 2:**

```
int popcto_test2(unsigned int bitmap[], int idx){
int i = 0,      // index
    count = 0;  // number of set bits
do {
    // Each node contains 8 bitmaps
    count += (bitmap[i/32] & (1 << (i & 31)));
    ++i;
} while (i < idx);

return count;
}
```

**popcto_test3 ns=28**
One (perhaps) interesting point of note about this one is that although it is the fastest, if optimization levels 2 or 3 are used (-O2/-O3) the result it gives is incorrect.

```
int popcto_test3(unsigned int bitmap[], int idx){
int i = 0,      // index
    count = 0,  // number of set bits
    map = idx/32;
while (i < map){
    // Each node contains 8 bitmaps
    count += __builtin_popcount(bitmap[i]);
    ++i;
}

count += __builtin_popcount(bitmap[map] & ((1<<idx)-1));
return count;
}
```

**avg popcto_test4 ns=74** (Modified Peter Wegner Method)

```
int popcto_test4(unsigned int bitmap[], int idx){
int i = 0,      // index
    j = 0,
    count = 0,  // number of set bits
    map = idx/32;
unsigned int temp = 0;

while (i < map){
    temp = bitmap[i];
    j = 0;
    while(temp){
        temp &= temp - 1;
        ++j;
    }
    count += j;
    ++i;
}
temp = bitmap[i] & ((1<<idx)-1);
j = 0;
while(temp){
    temp &= temp - 1;
    ++j;
}
return count + j;
}
```

Comment: How about `__builtin_popcount `?

Comment: I would shift left to get rid of the undesired bits, and then do the popcnt (if you have to cast to `uint64_t` that's fine). I've used popcnt for 64 bits, but I guess there is also a popcnt for 32

Comment: @EugeneSh. I read up on `__builtin_popcount`. If I have understood correctly, it allows for a total population count rather than a population count up to a given bit position.

Comment: You can use `__builtin_popcount(n&((1<<k)-1))` to count bits set up to the kth bit.

Comment: @AlainMerigot Awesome, thanks! the trick used at the end there actually opens up a lot of possibilities in itself. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @AlainMerigot: Careful because that is undefined behavior for `k == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions, I decided to pit all the methods I had come across head to head as I couldn't find any similar tests.

[image: Population Count Head to Head on Ryzen 1700]
N.B. The population counts shown are for indexes up to `argv[1]`, not a popcount of `argv[1]` - 8x 32-bit arrays make up 256 bits. [The code used to produce these results can be seen here.](https://gist.github.com/AR-Calder/a3b0e5bad96874afb4b8b28ff753450b)

On my Ryzen 1700,For my usage, the fastest population count was (often) the one on page 180 of the [Software Optimization Guide for AMD64 Processors](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/25112.PDF). This (often) remains true for larger population counts too.

```
unsigned int population_count(int temp){
    // Software Optimization Guide for AMD64 Processors - Page 180
    temp = temp - ((temp >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    temp = (temp & 0x33333333) + ((temp >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((temp + (temp >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

I don't have a side by side comparison for this but if you happen to be using CUDA; the intrinsic `__popc` method is the fastest, shortly followed by the wegner method. The AMD64 Method is the 2nd slowest (after bitwise only), I believe this is due to increased occupancy / register usage compared to all other methods.